Power button does nothing, I/O led (hdd activity lamp) turns on instantly after plugging in
it's an HP Z240, was all fine until it refused to boot up (GPU-Issue diagnostic beeps) after disabling legacy support (to enable secureboot); didn't have any uefi gpu (CPU's a xeon, no igpu.) so I couldn't get into bios to enable it again,
carried it to the nearest computer hardware maintenance, he said he couldn't resolve the issue, but when í took it home, it didn't power on at all, with the i/o lamp always on right after plugging it in. (That's the current issue)
any idea's greatly appreciated.

Contact HP customer support.

"it refused to boot up... after disabling legacy support..." Are you stating this issue only occurred after you opened BIOS/UEFI and disabled legacy support? Are you also stating you cannot get to BIOS to change that back? Info needed -- edit question.
